# Count nodes in a tree non recursively.

Tags: c#, .net, nodes

In an interview recently i was asked to count all the nodes in a tree given this node class.

```
class Node
{
    public List<Node> Children;
}
```

While i had a brain fart during the interview i wrote this out this morning in a few minutes which does it recursively.

```
int CountNodes(Node node, int count)
{
    count++;

    if(node.Children == null)
        return count;

    foreach(Node n in node.Children)
    {
        count = CountNodes(n, count);
    }

    return count;
}
```

However during the conversation we discussed problems with a recursive approach. One being a stack overflow.

What would a non recursive method be to solve this. I seem to be struggling with it.

Comment: So, you implemented a [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) - an alternative is [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which is basically a [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Finally, if you control the implementation of `Node`, one could also increment a child-counter on a `Node` instance when a child gets added (on the root).

Comment: The usual way is to use a Queue. The algorithm is straightforward: Start by adding the root nodes. Then while the queue is not empty: dequeue, perform whatever operation on it, then add all its children to the queue, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You could start off with a `List<Node> nodes` containing all root nodes. The method would loop until there are no nodes left on the "current" level, and replace the `nodes` list with the children of that level on each iteration:

```
List<Node> nodes = GetRootNodes();
int total = 0;
while (nodes.Count > 0) 
{
    total += nodes.Count;
    List<Node> children = new List<Node>();
    foreach (Node node in nodes)
    {
        children.AddRange(node.Children);
    }

    nodes = children;
}
```

Comment: [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is the technical *term* for that :)

Answer (score 2):

[Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

```
int CountNodes(Node node)
{
    int count = 0;
    List<Node> nodesToSearch = new List<Node>();
    nodesToSearch.Add(node);

    while(nodesToSearch.Count > 0){
        count += nodesToSearch.Count;

        List<Node> newNodes = new List<Node>();
        foreach(Node nodeToSearch in nodesToSearch){
            if(nodeToSearch.Children != null)
                 newNodes.AddRange(nodeToSearch.Children);
        }
        nodesToSearch = newNodes;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Nice, you need return the count and check for nodeToSearch.Children being null. But it works.